# HDMI Screen losing signal in Safe mode

Tags: hdmi, safe-mode, signal

I recently got a ransomware at my computer so I decided to start up in Safe mode to do a recovery but when I choose Safe mode my screen turns black and the message "No HDMI Signal" appears. I've tried restarting the computer but the same thing happens. Should I try temporarily connecting a DVI Screen to see if a different result occurs or is this caused by something really simple?

Any answer is appreciated.

BTW I have a BENQ "24 screen if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with a default port on the video card. Had you gone to Safe mode before and did it work normally? Also do you have an analog port on the video card? I have seen some default to analog when confused.

It's possible the drivers got messed up by the virus to keep you from Safe mode. Since you didn't specify your OS you may want to try system restore and go back to before the ransomware was installed.  Be aware of what software you had installed between now and then as they may need to be reinstalled. With luck the restore will allow Safe mode to work and may even get the autostart removed for the virus. It might be a better idea to get a bartpe or some other rescue disk like trinity rescue to boot off of and clean the system up before booting up after the system restore.

Comment: my os is 32x vista and can you system restore without entering safemode?

Comment: to a certain date I mean

Comment: havent played with vista so not 100% sure.  win7 you can go to the recovery consol boot option its what the xp recovery console was plus system restore and some others...  I suspect vista has that option but am not sure. hopefully you made a recovery cd when you first got the pc.  not sure if you can do one now or not.

Comment: I worked it out another way thanks alot anyways :)